# How to install Mac keyboard and trackpad drivers

Tags: drivers, keyboard, touchpad, mac

I have recently installed Ubuntu on my Mac book Pro 2016, and noticed that the built in keyboard, and the track-pad are frozen. I have looked up how to install the drivers but I don't understand a how to use GitHub and got lost really quick.

What is the fastest way I can get these drivers installed and working? I am using an external keyboard and mouse for now but would not like to in the long run.

Comment: After spending many hours on the exact same issue, I finally ran across this link:
https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/dkms/#installing-modules I am using a Macbook 15,1 (15" 2018 MBP) and Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

*The guide below is taken from  https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/dkms/#installing-modules*

Note that two of the steps (about loading the modules either at boot or immediately) are **optional** (and have been marked as such), and should not be necessary for Ubuntu.

---

#### Preparation

First install the `dkms` module

Next check that your kernel isn't outdated (or your distribution uses different module versions from those used later) by running:

```
dkms status or ls -l /usr/src
```

If the version of `apple-bce` is `0.1` then uninstall the old modules (to avoid incompatibility issues):

```
sudo dkms uninstall -m apple-bce -v 0.1
sudo dkms uninstall -m apple-ibridge -v 0.1
sudo rm -r /usr/src/apple-bce-0.1
sudo rm -r /usr/src/apple-ibridge-0.1
sudo rm -r /var/lib/dkms/apple-bce
sudo rm -r /var/lib/dkms/apple-ibridge
```

#### Installation

1. Install the BCE (Buffer Copy Engine) module for Keyboard and Audio

   - If you are on Arch, then use Aunali1's [`apple-bce-dkms-git`](https://github.com/aunali1/apple-bce-arch/releases) package
   - Otherwise, run

     ```
     sudo git clone https://github.com/t2linux/apple-bce-drv /usr/src/apple-bce-r183.c884d9c
     ```
   - Create a `dkms.conf` file in `/usr/src/apple-bce-r183.c884d9c` and put in the following:

     ```
     PACKAGE_NAME="apple-bce"
     PACKAGE_VERSION="r183.c884d9c"
     MAKE[0]="make KVERSION=$kernelver"
     CLEAN="make clean"
     BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="apple-bce"
     DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/kernel/drivers/misc"
     AUTOINSTALL="yes"
     ```
   - Now run `sudo dkms install -m apple-bce -v r183.c884d9c`. If on a live ISO, use `sudo dkms install -m apple-bce -v r183.c884d9c -k x.x.x-mbp` instead and change `x.x.x-mbp` to the kernel that you have installed, as by default `dkms` will try to build the module for the kernel that the live ISO is using, which will most likely be older.
2. Install the Touchbar and Ambient Light sensor modules

   - Run `sudo git clone https://github.com/t2linux/apple-ib-drv /usr/src/apple-ibridge-0.1`
   - Run `sudo dkms install -m apple-ibridge -v 0.1`. If on a live ISO, use `sudo dkms install -m apple-ibridge -v 0.1 -k x.x.x-mbp` instead and change `x.x.x-mbp` to the kernel that you have installed, as by default `dkms` will try to build the module for the kernel that the live ISO is using, which will most likely be older.
3. Load the modules into the kernel - **optional**

   Note that this is only required if you wish to run the modules immediately (instead of after a reboot).

   If you are installing modules from a live iso the commands will fail as the modules have only been installed for the kernel you specified.

   ```
   sudo modprobe apple_bce
   sudo modprobe apple_ib_tb
   sudo modprobe apple_ib_als
   ```

The touchbar and the keyboard should now work.

For audio some additional configuration is required, see [Audio config files](http://Audio%20Config%20guide).

#### Making the modules load at boot time - optional

In Ubuntu, these should *already* be set:

```
echo "apple-bce
apple-ib_tb
apple-ib-als
brcmfmac" >> /etc/modules-load.d/t2.conf
```

If you don't want (for example) the touch bar modules, you can omit them from this command. `brcmfmac` is needed to use the internal Wi-Fi chip, refer to the [Wi-Fi guide](https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/wifi/) for details on how to set that up.

#### Configuring the Touchbar module

The Touchbar module offers some modes to set. In `/etc/modprobe.d/apple-tb.conf`, set `fnmode (options apple-ib-tb fnmode=x)` to one of the following options:

- 0: Only show F1-F12
- 1: Show media and brightness controls, use the fn key to switch to F1-12
- 2: Show F1-F12, use the fn key to switch to media and brightness controls
- 3: Only show media and brightness controls
- 4: Only show the escape key

#### Fixing suspend

Copy [this script](https://github.com/mikeeq/mbp-fedora/blob/f34/files/suspend/rmmod_tb.sh)

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "${1}" = "pre" ]; then
  modprobe -r apple_ib_tb hid_apple
elif [ "${1}" = "post" ]; then
  modprobe hid_apple apple_ib_tb
fi
```

to `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/rmmod_tb.sh`

Then run

```
sudo chmod 755 /lib/systemd/system-sleep/rmmod_tb.sh
sudo chown root:root /lib/systemd/system-sleep/rmmod_tb.sh
```

This unloads the Touchbar modules as they can cause issues for suspend.

#### Possible Issues

The `apple_ib_als` module can cause issues, if you find your computer hanging at shutdown, or having BCE errors at boot, try blacklisting it by running

```
sudo sh -c "echo blacklist apple-ib-als" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

or removing it from `/etc/modules-load.d/t2.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable "Install third-party software for graphics and WIFI hardware and additional media formats" during installation? Also, if you have a external mouse, can you try using that? Theres also "Additional Drivers" in the "Software & Updates app, see if the drivers for the trackpad/keyboard are there.