# Installing Ubuntu (LTS 20.04) on Macbook

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro

I've been preparing to get my (2010 Mid) Macbook Pro ready for Ubuntu. The software is becoming slower, and I've always wanted to have an Ubuntu PC of some sort to practice Linux terminal stuff (and its a new OS, which is always nice to trial)

Recently I've heard that I have to install drivers on my Macbook once I get Ubuntu onto it, otherwise, the trackpad and keyboard, and webcam won;t work. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

this model right?
https://support.apple.com/kb/sp583?locale=en_US

have you installed ubuntu yet?
you can first check if your hardware works by trying ubuntu from the flash drive, if it doesnt work, then you can proceed to installing drivers

in the installation enable "Install third-party software for graphics and WIFI hardware and additional media formats" during installation

if none of the steps above work, check this: [How to install Mac keyboard and trackpad drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033365/how-to-install-mac-keyboard-and-trackpad-drivers)